# How to write to an existing excel file with openpyxl, while preserving pivot tables

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, openpyxl

I have this excel file with multiple sheet. One sheet contains two pivot tables, normal table based on the data from pivot, some graphs based on pivot as well.

I am updating the sheets without pivots using below code. The content for these sheets are generated as dataframes and straight away right the data frame.

**Method 1**

```
book = xl.load_workbook(fn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fn,engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
DF.to_excel(writer, 'ABC', header=None, startrow=book.active.max_row)
writer.save()
```

But, when the file is written, the pivot table is converted to plain text. The solution I found to preserve the pivot table is to read and write the workbook using below methods.

**Method 2**

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename=updating_file)
sheet = workbook["Pivot"]
pivot = sheet._pivots[0]
# any will do as they share the same cache
pivot.cache.refreshOnLoad = True
workbook.save(filename=updating_file)
```

This adds an additional row to the pivot table as 'Value' which ruins the values of the tables based on the pivot.
[image]

According to [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/295/pivot-table-changed-to-plain-text-after) using `pd.ExcelWriter` would not preserve pivot tables. The only example I found to update an existing excel file with data frame requires pandas ExcelWriter.

Some help would be highly appreciated, as I am unable to find a method to fulfill both requirements.

Only option I can see so far is to write the data parts with Pandas. Then, drop the existing Pivot sheet and copy a sheet from original fie. But, again I have to find a way to clear the table based on the pivot and rewrite with openpyxl using 2nd method. **(We can't copy sheets between workbooks)**

Answer (score 1):

Stick with your **Method 1**: if you convert the `df` to a pivot table in pandas, and *then* export to excel, it will work.

**An example:**

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# create dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky'], 
      'B': ['Masters', 'Graduate', 'Graduate', 'Masters', 'Graduate'], 
      'C': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24]}) 

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values ='A', index =['B', 'C'], 
                         columns =['B'], aggfunc = np.sum)

table.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

**Outputs**

[image: Excel Output]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to iterate the data frame as rows. If it was adding rows to the end of exisitng table, this would have been much easier. Since, I have to insert rows to middle, I followed below approach to insert blank rows and write the cell values.

```
current_sheet.insert_rows(idx=11, amount=len(backend_report_df))
sheet_row_idx = 11
is_valid_row = False
for row in dataframe_to_rows(backend_report_df, index=True, header=True):
    is_valid_row = False
    for col_idx in range (0, len(row)):
        if col_idx == 0 and row[col_idx] is None:
            logger.info("Header row/blank row")
            break
        else:
            is_valid_row = True
            if col_idx != 0:
                current_sheet.cell(row=sheet_row_idx, column=col_idx).value = row[col_idx]
    if is_valid_row:
        sheet_row_idx = sheet_row_idx + 1
```